# How to extend superagent with proxy method?

Tags: typescript, superagent

I haven't found any TypeScript definitions for `superagent-proxy`. So when I try to compile my TypeScript application to JavaScript, I get the error message:

> ts: Property 'proxy' does not exist on type 'SuperAgentRequest'.

```
import * as request from 'superagent';
import * as withProxy from 'superagent-proxy';

withProxy(request);

request
    .get(...)
    .proxy(proxy)
```

I have created a file with declarations, but I don't know what more to do.

```
declare module 'superagent-proxy';
```

I guess I want to define some higher order function that takes a superagent and returns a superagent with proxy somehow.

This is my best attempt this far:

```
import * as request from 'superagent';

declare module 'superagent-proxy' {
    interface SuperAgentRequestWithProxy extends request.SuperAgentStatic {
        proxy(url: string): SuperAgentRequestWithProxy;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work and I'm not even sure its close to correct.

> Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'superagent-proxy'
>   resolves to an untyped module at
>   '.../node_modules/superagent-proxy/index.js', which cannot be
>   augmented

Answer (score 3):

you need to add the type dependency as well, importing only the super agent proxy dependency is not sufficient, you need to have two imports :
"superagent-proxy": "^2.1.0",   under dependencies
"@types/superagent-proxy": "^2.0.0", under dev dependencies

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a shot (it's been a while and I have not used the proxy since it's for debugging only...) FWIW, those types did not exist when posed this question. They only got created in January this year: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commits/master/types/superagent-proxy

Comment: maybe there was something else at that time, i faced the same problem so i came here. when i found the solution i posted it. hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

To install

```
npm i superagent
npm i superagent-proxy
npm i --save-dev suuperagent-proxy
```

To use

```
import * as superagent from 'superagent';
import enableProxy from 'superagent-proxy';
enableProxy(superagent);
```

Then:

```
await superagent.get(...).proxy(proxyUrl)
```

Comment: There's a typo in the 3rd install cmd line, sUUperagent-proxy instead of sUperagent-proxy